# Where are the executables of JetBrains products when installed via Toolbox app?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-toolbox

I'm using an Ubuntu based Linux distribution and want to use the Godot game engine with the PyCharm IDE. To use this IDE I have to configure it

(taken from [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/editor/external_editor.html))

[image]

Unfortunately I don't know the correct value for `Exec Path`. I found the installed data at

> ~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P

but I wasn't able to find an executable inside it. Would someone mind telling me where to find the executable for a single JetBrains IDE?

(Bonus points for Linux, Mac and Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to go into further subdirectories.

In windows I see the following path..

`C:\Users\<myUserName>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-C\ch-0\221.5080.212`

Here, under `ch-0`, I see many different build directories out of which latest one is `221.5080.212`

Comment: thanks :) I found a shell script `pycharm.sh` at `~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/221.5080.212/bin`, I will give it a try